# mysql right join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, join

When I use right join I get the same results as using left join or just join. Can anyone show me where I have gone wrong?

I have 3 tables as follows:

### langugages

id

code     eg "hu","en"

### language_default

id

text

### language_translations

id

lang_id           (FK the id of the language in the languages table)

default_lang_id   (FK the id of the text in the languages_default table)

text              (the translation)

When I execute the following query, I expect to get all of the hungarian translations from the language_translations table and all of the text fields from the language_default table with a null value where there is no hungarian translation.

```
SELECT `language_translations`.`text`
     , `language_default`.`text` 
  FROM `languages`
     , `language_translations` 
        RIGHT JOIN `language_default` ON `language_default`.`id` = `language_translations`.`default_lang_id`
  WHERE `languages`.`code` = 'hu' 
    AND `languages`.`id` = `language_translations`.`lang_id`
```

Instead I only get text from the language_default table where there are translations for that text in the tranlsation table. I would expect that behaviour from a left join or normal join but not a right join. Any ideas why I am not getting all of the entries from the langugage_defailt table?

Comment: Are you after every entry from `language_default` for each `language_translation` (in which case you want a `CROSS JOIN`) or do you simply want to ensure that every entry from `language_default` is joined to `language_translation` at least once (in which case this is what your current `RIGHT JOIN` should be doing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using combination of normal join and rights join in wrong way. You can use as per below query.

2nd thing right join means you will get all record from right side and corresponding records from left side and if left side does not have corresponding record then it will show NULL.

Left join is its reverse.

Normal join or comma join will provide only common rows.

So if your tables only have common rows then all joins will provide same results.

```
SELECT 
`language_translations`.`text` , `language_default`.`text` 
FROM `languages` AS l
JOIN `language_translations` AS t
ON l.`id` = t.`lang_id` AND l.`code` = 'hu'
RIGHT JOIN `language_default` AS d
ON d.`id` = t.`default_lang_id`;
```

Comment: Many thanks, I had to alter the field list using the aliases instead of the table names and it worked. Thank you so much for your time. Can I ask why the normal join using the where clause did not work? I thought this worked just like a join statement. Or is it because the where clause is being applied to the right join as well as the normal join in my original?

Comment: In normal join (also known as comma join) you can put your join condition in where clause but in left or right join you should mention it in on clause..you can say that join with on clause is standard and to put it in where clause is just a leverage in comma join...further for your information I put l.code='hu' just after on clause to filter data first even you can put it at the end in where clause also.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix implicit joins and explicit joins.  A simple rule is:  don't use `,` in the `from` clause.  The following restructures your query to use `left outer join`:

```
SELECT `language_translations`.`text`,  ld.`text` 
FROM language_default ld left outer join
     language_translations lt
     on ld.`id` = lt.`default_lang_id` left outer join
     `languages` l
     on l.`id` = lt.`lang_id` and l.`code` = 'hu' ;
```

When using outer joins, you need to be very careful about where additional conditions go.  Conditions on the driving table (the first a left outer join, the last for a right outer join) can go in the `where` clause.  For other tables, the conditions should go in the `on` clause.  Otherwise, they turn the outer join into an inner for the simple reason that (almost) any comparison to `NULL` is equivalent to false.